# Compiling asm with gcc - ubuntu

Tags: gcc, makefile

I've been trying to compile some language (CISC) that my professor created which is pseudo assembly. He wanted us to make a makefile and compile the file with .asm extension using gcc.
This is the makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES: .asm
all:schemeCompiler

schemeCompiler:target.o
       gcc -g -m32 -Wall -o schemeCompiler target.o

target.o: target.asm
       gcc -m32 -g -Wall -ansi -c -o target.o target.asm

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f *.o schemeCompiler
```

And this is the error I get:

```
gcc -m32 -g -Wall -ansi -c -o target.o target.asm
gcc: warning: target.asm: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc -g -m32 -Wall -o schemeCompiler target.o
gcc: error: target.o: No such file or directory 
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I've put the makefile with the asm file in the same directory

Thanks !

***We've figured out the problem , we weren't running the make command right. Also the makefile wasn't right:

```
.SUFFIXES: .asm
    all:schemeCompiler

 schemeCompiler:$@
 gcc -g -m32 -Wall -o schemeCompiler $@

 %: %.asm
  gcc -x c -o $@ $<


 .PHONY: clean
  clean:
   rm -f *.o schemeCompiler
```

Comment: So what sort of file is target.asm?  If it is assembler, then it doesn't need compiling (compiling is what gets you to assembler, more or less).  If it needs some sort of processing to become actual assembler, you need to tell gcc what language it's in (either by providing the "proper" extension, or using the flag (-x as I recall)).  (EDIT: gcc assumes assembler files end in .s.)

Comment: @tabstop 
This file is actually in c, but he wrote a lot of "macros" so that it would look like assembly. That's why Im guessing I need the compiling.
And I do have the extension written ".asm" (which he asked for).
Still I don't understand why this error could occur. Maybe I don't get the idea of how the makefile works...
Thanks! :)